# os.listdir() in python doesn't show all the files of directory. It skipped few of them

Tags: python

I tried to open all the files(csv) of a directory and append a column to new dataframe. But, os.listdir() doesn't show all files of the directory.. skipped few of them

```
import os
path1=r'D:\data files'
filenames=os.listdir(path1)
print(filenames)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected and actual output of your code. What files are you seeing skipped, specifically?

Comment: `glob.glob(r"D:\data files\*.csv")` might be better suited for your case since it will only list `.csv` files.

Comment: Is there a pattern by which the files are left out of the resulting list? Do those maybe contain irregular characters?... You can try `path1 = u'D:/data files'`.

Answer (score -1):

You could try doing it with system commands

```
files = os.system("cd /data\ files && ls")
```

You might have to add in the path of the directory but this should to the trick. Hope this helps